# the number of images, using "len()"

Tags: python, parsing

I need to count the number of images (in this case 1 image). Apparently using "len()"?

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="detail-headline">
    Fotogal&#233;ria
        </div>
<div class="detail-indent">
    <table id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_containerHolder_mainContentHolder_innnerContentHolder_ZakazkaControl_ZakazkaObrazky1_ObrazkyDataList" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="width:25%;">
            <div id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_containerHolder_mainContentHolder_innnerContentHolder_ZakazkaControl_ZakazkaObrazky1_ObrazkyDataList_ctl02_PictureContainer">
                <a title="1-izb. Kaspická" class="highslide detail-img-link" onclick="return hs.expand(this);" href="/imgcache/cache231/3186-000393~8621457~640x480.jpg"><img src="/imgcache/cache231/3186-000393~8621457~120x120.jpg" class="detail-img" width="89" height="120" alt="1-izb. Kaspická" /></a>
            </div>
        </td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I used before HTMLParser and the number of images must be added to "self.srcData".. 
Previous code:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):  
    if tag == 'div' and len(attrs) > 1 and attrs[1][0] == 'class' and attrs[1][1] == 'detail-headline' \
      and self.srcData[self.getpos()[0]].strip() == u'Realitn&#225; kancel&#225;ria':
      self.status = 2

    if self.status == 2 and tag == 'div' and len(attrs) > 0 and attrs[0][0] == 'class' and attrs[0][1] == 'name':
      self.record[-1] = decode(self.srcData[self.getpos()[0]].strip())
      self.status = 0
```

Then (check start tag).. Like this?

```
if tag == 'div' and len(attrs) > 0 and attrs[0][0] == 'class' and attrs[0][1] == 'detail-headline' \
      and self.srcData[self.getpos()[0]].strip() == 'Fotogal&#233;ria':
      self.status = 3
```

Is it ok? And...? Thanks.

---

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import HTMLParser
import codecs
import time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# decode string
def decode(istr):
  ostr = u''
  idx = 0
  while idx < len(istr):
    add = True
    if istr[idx] == '&' and len(istr) > idx + 1 and istr[idx + 1] == '#':
      iend = istr.find(';', idx)
      if iend > idx:
        ostr += unichr(int(istr[idx + 2:iend]))
        idx = iend
        add = False
    if add:
      ostr += istr[idx]
    idx += 1
  return ostr

# parser 1
class FlatDetailParser (HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
  def __init__ (self):
    HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)

  def loadDetails(self, link):
    self.record = (len(self.characts) + 1) * ['']
    self.status = 0
    self.index = -1
    self.reset()
    request = urllib2.Request(link)
    data = urllib2.urlopen(request)  # URL obtained from the next class
    self.srcData = []
    for line in data:
      line = line.decode('utf8')
      self.srcData.append(line)
    for line in self.srcData:
      self.feed(line)
    self.close()
    return self.record


  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'div' and len(attrs) > 1 and attrs[1][0] == 'class' and attrs[1][1] == 'detail-headline' \
      and self.srcData[self.getpos()[0]].strip() == u'Realitn&#225; kancel&#225;ria':
      self.status = 2

    if self.status == 2 and tag == 'div' and len(attrs) > 0 and attrs[0][0] == 'class' \
      and attrs[0][1] == 'name':
      self.record[-1] = decode(self.srcData[self.getpos()[0]].strip())
      self.status = 0
```

...and next class of parser, and adding data in to the txt file.

When I use BeautifulSoup.. What is soup=BeautifulSoup(???). How can I add to srcData?
This can be combined? How?

Comment: Can you add a second image to the example, so we can understand the structure of the document better?

Answer (score 3):

Your job will be easier if you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup)

Perhaps something like this

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeaufitulSoup
def count_images(htmltext)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    return len(soup.findAll('div',{'class':'detail-indent'}))
```

Or using **lxml**

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
def count_images(htmltext)
    return len([e.attrib for e in fromstring(htmltext).findall('div')
                             if e.attrib.get('class')=='detail-indent'])
```

Comment: Development on BeautifulSoup has come to a halt. It makes more sense to recommend lxml (http://codespeak.net/lxml/), which is still current, supported, improving software.

Comment: I know a little BeautifulSoup as a beginner, but I don´t know to combine HTMLParser (and using "len()"). And it is necessary. Previous code (200 lines) is written with him.. (POST method, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Just for a lark, I tried a pyparsing approach.  Pyparsing includes some methods to help construct matching patterns for HTML tags, which include matches for attributes, unexpected whitespace, single or double quotes, and other hard-to-predict HTML tag gotchas.  Here is a pyparsing solution (assumes your HTML source has been read into a string variable 'html'):

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags

# makeHTMLTags returns patterns for both opening and closing 
# tags, we just want the opening ones
aTag = makeHTMLTags("A")[0]
imgTag = makeHTMLTags("IMG")[0]

# find the matching tags
tagMatches = (aTag|imgTag).searchString(html)

# yes, use len() to see how many there are
print len(tagMatches)

# get the actual image names
for t in tagMatches:
    if t.startA:
        print t.href
    if t.startImg:
        print t.src
```

Prints:

```
2
/imgcache/cache231/3186-000393~8621457~640x480.jpg
/imgcache/cache231/3186-000393~8621457~120x120.jpg
```

Comment: Nice solution. BeautifulSoup, lxml, pyparsing. And again.. What is html in my case? I don´t have any url of type "http:// www...... com/..... html". And how I add to srcData (next import in to the txt/csv file)? I like these methods, but don´t use in difficult cases.

Comment: Edited to explain that 'html' is a string variable containing the HTML source you are searching for image refs.  I don't understand your other questions.